# A subset of a polynomial ring and its ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $P=K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be a polynomial ring over a field $K$ and $I = (f)$ be a principal ideal in $P$ generated by $f \in P - \{0 \}$. Moreover let $L \subset \{x_1, \dots, x_n \}$ and $\hat{P} = K\{x_i : x_i \notin L \}$. Show $I \cap \hat{P} = (0) \iff f \notin \hat{P}$. (Exercise 4, Section 3.4 from Kreuzer and Robbiano, *Computational Commutative Algebra*, vol. 1.)

So I know that in one direction, if $f \not\in \hat{P}$, then $f$ contains a variable in $L$, but then $\hat{P}$ cannot contain any variable that is not in $L$. So the intersection must be $0$. (this need some justification...?) I am not sure about the other way. If someone could show me both, that would be good.

Comment: Its quite funny how someone would formulate an exercise this way. Why not take $\hat{P}$ to be $K[x_1, \dotsc, x_m]$ for some $m \leq n$ and then notice that you can actually pick any subset of variables due to symmetry reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the forward direction:

If $I\cap{}\hat{P}=(0)$, then since $f\in{}I$, we have $f\notin{}\hat{P}$, since $f\neq{}0$ and $f\notin{}(0)$ (since P is an integral domain).

And backwards:

If $f\notin{}\hat{P}$, then note that every element of $I$ is of the form $h=\sum_{i=1}^ng_if=gf$ where the $g_i\in{}P$ and $g=\sum_{i=1}^ng_i$.  Since $f\notin{}\hat{P}$ then it must contain a variable of $L$ since degree of polynomials is additive, which means that $gf$ must have a variable in $L$, unless $g=0$, which would make $gf=0$.  Therefore $I\cap\hat{P}=(0)$.

Comment: Maybe one could mention the notion of degree for your latest argument. The degree (with respect to one fixed variable) is well known (from the analysis of polynomials in one variable) to be additive. Hence any variable, which occurs in $f$, cannot be somehow canceled in $gf$ (unless $g=0$).

Comment: Wait hold on, on your last line. If $gf$ contains a variable in $L$, how does that show the intersection is $0$? Am I missing something here?

Comment: $gf$ contains a variable in $L$, hence $gf \notin \hat P$. This holds for any $g \neq 0$. So the only element in $(f) \cap \hat P$ is the zero polynomial.

Comment: sorry this is probably really obvious btu why does it matter if $g \neq 0$?

Comment: It does not hold for any $g$, so it would be a lie, if we dont mention this...But of course the fact, that it does not hold for $g=0$ does not bother us.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections!  You're right, needed to acknowledge the zero polynomial.